# Text running through table cell after forced linebreak

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I’m trying to fit some text in a table, but the text keeps running through the table cells. I’ve already specified a fixed column width for the text using the `p{}` command. Initially, this worked, but then I also needed some forced linebreaks and once I implemented that using a new command, the `p{}` was overruled somehow, and the text runs through the cells again. Can someone help me fix this problem?
The code I used looks something like this:

```
    \begin{landscape}

    \newcommand{\cellenter}[2][l]{%

    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
    \begin{table}[t]\footnotesize 
    \caption{Caption}\label{table:table_cable_lay_2}
      \begin{tabular*}{1.4\textwidth}{| p{0.32\textwidth} | p{0.32\textwidth} | p{0.32\textwidth} | p{0.32\textwidth} |}
          \hline\hline
          \textbf{Scenarios} &\textbf{Advantages} &\textbf{Disadvantages} &\textbf{Remarks} \\ [0.5ex]
          \hline

          \textit{Title of the cell} This text remains within the cell width because there are no forced linebreaks in this cell.

          &\cellenter[t]{+ Advantage 1 \\ + Advantage 2}

          &\cellenter[t]{- Disadvantage 1 \\ - Disadvantage 2}

          &\cellenter[t]{ There is some text here that runs through the cell width. \\ There is some text here that runs through the cell width.} \\[1ex]
          \hline
      \end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
```

The pdf output that I get looks like this:
[image: table 1]

Comment: Please make edit that into a complete document so we can run it locally, also you can upload the image but remove the `!` so that it becomes a link rather than showing the image inline. Someone with edit privileges will put it back

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear what the intention of your `\cellcenter` is but it puts all its content into an inner tabular `l` column. `l` columns never linebreak they are always set to their natural width as a single line.

You can use a blank line to start a new paragraph within the table cells or `\newline` if you want a forced break without a new paragraph.

---

[image]

I fixed a few other things in your markup at the same time:
(Using math mode to get matching +/ and using tabular rather than tabular* as you had no stretching between columns)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

   \begin{landscape}

    \begin{table}[t]\footnotesize 
    \caption{Caption}\label{table:table_cable_lay_2}
      \begin{tabular}{| p{0.32\textwidth} | p{0.32\textwidth} | p{0.32\textwidth} | p{0.32\textwidth} |}
          \hline\hline
          \textbf{Scenarios} &\textbf{Advantages} &\textbf{Disadvantages} &\textbf{Remarks} \\ [0.5ex]
          \hline

          \textit{Title of the cell} This text remains within the cell width because there are no forced linebreaks in this cell.

          &$+$ Advantage 1 \par  $+$ Advantage 2

          &$-$ Disadvantage 1 \par $-$ Disadvantage 2

          &There is some text here that runs through the cell width. \par There is some text here that runs through the cell width. \\[1ex]
          \hline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

---

To control alignment within the cells it is easiest to add

```
 \usepackage{array}
```

then you can inject `\raggedright` into each entry. If I understand your comment correctly you could use

```
\begin{tabular}{|%
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.32\textwidth}|%
p{0.32\textwidth}|%
p{0.32\textwidth}|%
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.32\textwidth}|%
}
```

or did you mean:

```
\begin{tabular}{|%
p{0.32\textwidth}|%
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.32\textwidth}|%
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.32\textwidth}|%
p{0.32\textwidth}|%
}
```

Comment: The text now runs inside the table cells, which I wanted. But the second column is now aligned both left and right, whereas I only want it to be aligned left. How can I fix this?

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: I've used your code for the second column in the following manner.
\begin{tabular}{| 
p{0.32\textwidth} | *4{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.32\textwidth} | } p{0.32\textwidth} | p{0.32\textwidth} 
|}

The first column is now fully aligned (left and right), whereas columns 2,3,4 are aligned left only. How do I make sure only columns 2 and 3 are aligned left? I would like to have column 1 and 4 to be fully aligned (both left and right).

Comment: No the `*4` meant 4 columns, I meant use that line for the entire tabular specification. so that has 7 columns. forget the *4 if all columns are not teh same I'll update the answer as code formatting in comments is rubbish